# Get details of the build after it finishes on bamboo and publish them using a final task/script

Tags: webhooks, bamboo

I am currently looking for a solution that will enable me to fetch the details of a build after it completes and use a python script to send these results to MS teams channel. I want to add a final task to my existing build which can do so. I did try to configure a MS teams webhook under 'Notifications' but it didnt work. I now want to add a script as a final task which will run after the build and publish details of the build to a MS teams channel. Any way to get the details of the build into the python script ?

Answer (score 0):

> I did try to configure a MS teams webhook under 'Notifications' but it didnt work

Is there any error you see at all? I've seen lately that those can work.

Nevertheless, what I do is add a task last in the tasks list which creates a file, i.e. `success.marker`. Then check in a final task if the file is there. If it isn't it means that a task has failed. Consider the following as well:

- Create a task first in the list to clean the working directory and make sure there's no dangling `success.marker` file from previous runs.
- This approach won't catch failing final tasks.
- No need to use python for this. I send the build info to MS Teams webhook with a `curl` call.

This approach works well for deployment environment but not for plans because they may have multiple stages, i.e. multiple final tasks. In that case, I have a dedicated stage as last with a task which, instead of probing for a marker file, calls the Bamboo API to verify the status of all previous stages.

```
curl --fail --silent --show-error --connect-timeout 300\
--header 'X-Atlassian-Token: no-check'\
--user '[user]:[pass]'\
https://[bamboo]/rest/api/latest/result/${bamboo.planKey}-${bamboo.buildNumber}.json?expand=stages |\
jq --exit-status '.stages.stage | .[:-1] | map(select(.state != "Successful")) | length == 0' && {
  echo ok; // send success notification
} || {
  echo not ok; // send failure notifcation
}
```